# yii framework: how to i put a label to a radio button?

Tags: yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yii CHtml::radioButtonList - CSS to align horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128803/yii-chtmlradiobuttonlist-css-to-align-horizontally)

Am new to yii framework and the doubt might be silly!

I want to write a radio button code with its label next to it!

My code is as follows

```
<div class="column">
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'radio',false); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'radio'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'I need a room'); ?>
</div>
```

But it doesnt look nice! Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: please accept an answer(can be your own) and let this question be resolved, unless you wanna wait for better solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the code online! Sharing it of that it can be useful for someone in future

```
<?php echo  $form->radioButtonList($model,'radio',array('m'=>'male','f'=>'female'),array('separator'=>'', 'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create a label for the radiobutton created with the 'radio' attribute. Place this code after the 'echo $form->radiob.....'

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'radio', array('label' => 'My Label', 'style'=>'display:inline')); ?>
```

Use the display:inline or add a css class to get the label exactly where you want.